# armadillo c++: Efficient and concise way to multiply every row of a matrix by a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, armadillo

I am wondering if there is an efficient and concise way to do an element-wise multiplication of every row (or column) of an Armadillo C++ matrix by a vector. The row (or column) and vector are the same size.

For example, IF fmat::each_row() (and/or each_col()) could be used as an rvalue, I'd want something like this to compile (currently it won't compile):

```
#include <armadillo>

int main()
{
    using namespace arma;

    fmat m(20, 10);
    fvec v(10); // a column vector

    m.each_row() % v.t(); // Currently a compiler error.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From Armadillo version 5.6 onwards the `.each_col()` and `.each_row()` methods were expanded to handle out-of-place operations. Hence your suggested approach

```
m.each_row() % v.t();
```

should compile, see http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using the wrong operator. According to the documentation for [.each_row() and .each_col()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow), you need to specify an *in-place* operation (such as +=, -=, /=, %=). In other words, instead of  %, use %=, as below:

```
m.each_row() % v.t();    // wrong

m.each_row() %= v.t();   // right
```

Apart from the in-place operations, the only other allowed operation for .each_row() and .each_col() is "=" by itself.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I was aware of that. I was/am looking for a non-in-place "each_row". Which is why I said "IF...could be used as an rvalue". I guess the question needs rewording. What I'm looking for is something like Blitz++'s tensor index objects.

Comment: So you want something like `fmat x = m.each_row() % v.t()` ?  A straightforward workaround can be `fmat x = m; x.each_row() %= v.t()`.  Would that be general enough for your requirements?  You can always extend .each_row() to be more general, and send the patches upstream.

Comment: Essentially, that's what I do now. I'm looking for an rvalue version of each_row/each_col to implement an optimal expression like: (m1.each_row() % rv1 + m2.each_row() % rv2).each_col() % cv1. Currently I use each_row/col to create temporaries expand row vectors rv1 and rv2 into matrices with dims of m1 and m2 (MxN). Those get used like: (m1 % temp_rv1 + m2 % temp_rv2) % temp_cv1. But for big matrices (10K^2), that gets expensive. I see memory spikes of around 3 GB, which I'd like to reduce significantly. An rvalue version of each_row/col would help. Perhaps I should read the Armadillo code.